# Open new NSWindowController

Tags: cocoa, nswindowcontroller

I am new to Cocoa programming.

I have a main `NSWindowController` and would like to open a second sub `NSWindowController`. can't seem to find the code anyway.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

not sure if this is correct but i got this working as this is new for me as well

in the AppDelegate file i have

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    // Insert code here to initialize your application

    QuickBookingViewController * viewController = [[QuickBookingViewController alloc ] initWithNibName:@"QuickBookingViewController" bundle:nil];

    SimpleWindow *myWindow = [[SimpleWindow alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"SimpleWindow"];

    [self.window addChildWindow:[myWindow window] ordered:NSWindowBelow];

}
```

that seems to open up my view controller

recently i got this code from SO

```
   SimpleWindow *myWindow = [[SimpleWindow alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"SimpleWindow"];

    [myWindow showWindow:nil];
    [[myWindow window] makeMainWindow];
```

Comment: For me, the edited code initializes two window controllers instead of one. initWithWindowNibName initializes one, then, then showWindow initializes another but gives me no pointer to it!